# How to best return a record from inside an array with a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but the below code does not work when the currentRecord found is true.

What is the best way to iterate through an array and when a match is found, return that record?  I think forEach here is part AngularJS.

```
function getCurrentRecord() {

    homePageVideos.forEach(function(rec) {
        if (rec.currentRecord === true){
            return rec;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Looks correct, can you provide us with some more context

Comment: Do you want to return all matches or just the first match? Looking at the code, it appears you only want the the first.

Comment: Yes.   First (and only in my case).   Should my code work as is?  It seems not to when I debug in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) of `Array.prototype.forEach`:

> Note: There is no way to stop or break a `forEach()` loop. The solution is to use `Array.prototype.every()` or `Array.prototype.some()`. See example below.

Same goes for `angular.forEach`.

But if you were to use a simple for-loop, you could do it like so:

```
for (var i=0; i < homePageVideos.length; i++){
  var rec = homePageVideos[i];
  if (rec.currentRecord === true){
    return rec;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's an interesting question and this certainly seems like the best answer. The MDN reference also includes a polyfill should one need it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript provides several [array iteration functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods). I would use `filter()` but the solution would depend on the browser compatibility you require (IE9+, FF1.5+).

```
function getCurrentRecord() {
  return homePageVideos.filter(function(rec) {
    return rec.currentRecord
  });
}
```

Comment: Why not offer a better solution? The question asked what is the best way to iterate and return a match.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use angular filter. Inside controller you could accomplish this by using `$filter` inside controller

```
function getCurrentRecord() {
    var result = $filter('filter')(homePageVideos, true, true); //strict checking
    return result.length > 0? result[0]: [];
}
```